# How to pivot wider multiple columns on dataset and maintain a specific colum order?

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

My initial dataset

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                      name = c("james", "james", "peter", "anne", "anne", "anne"), 
                      trip_id = c(10,11,10,30,11,32),
                      date = c("2021/01/01", "2021/06/01","2021/08/01","2021/10/01","2021/10/21","2021/12/01"),
                      cost = c(100,150,3000,1200,1100,5000)
                      
), 
row.names = c(NA,-6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I require to pivot wider the date and the cost of each trip so they are both together in pairs. I think im closer but would appreciate your feedback.

My current code

```
df2= df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = trip_id, 
                               values_from = c(date, cost))
```

My desired result

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), 
                      name = c("james", "peter", "anne"), 
                      date_10 = c("2021/01/01","2021/08/01",NA),
                      cost_10 = c(100,3000,NA),
                      date_11 = c("2021/06/01",NA,"2021/10/21"),
                      cost_11 = c(150,NA,1100),
                      date_30 = c(NA,NA,"2021/10/01"),
                      cost_30 = c(NA,NA,1200),
                      date_32 = c(NA,NA,"2021/12/01"),
                      cost_32 = c(NA,NA,5000)             
                      
), 
row.names = c(NA,-3L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were quite close. We take the `trip_id` before `pivot_wider` to help reorder the columns. You may or may not need the `sort` depending on your desired result. If you just want pairs, there's no need to sort.

```r
library(tidyverse)
nums <- sort(unique(df1$trip_id))
nums <- as.character(nums)

df2 <- 
  df1 %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = trip_id, 
                values_from = c(date, cost)) %>%
    select(id, name, ends_with(nums))

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>      id name  date_10    cost_10 date_11 cost_11 date_30 cost_30 date_32 cost_32
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 james 2021/01/01     100 2021/0~     150 <NA>         NA <NA>         NA
#> 2     2 peter 2021/08/01    3000 <NA>         NA <NA>         NA <NA>         NA
#> 3     3 anne  <NA>            NA 2021/1~    1100 2021/1~    1200 2021/1~    5000
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you do need an additional `pivot_longer` step before changing your data shape into wide format. Note that I used `values_transform` argument in `pivot_longer` to change the class of `cost` to character so that I could combine it with `date` in the intermediate `val` variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(c(date, cost), names_to = "var", 
               values_to = "val", 
               values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(var, trip_id), values_from = val) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("cost"), as.double))


# A tibble: 3 x 10
     id name  date_10    cost_10 date_11    cost_11 date_30    cost_30 date_32    cost_32
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1     1 james 2021/01/01     100 2021/06/01     150 NA              NA NA              NA
2     2 peter 2021/08/01    3000 NA              NA NA              NA NA              NA
3     3 anne  NA              NA 2021/10/21    1100 2021/10/01    1200 2021/12/01    5000
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it is correct. Column numbering/Row numbering should not impact the data unless you have time series/panel data and some few exceptions.

Otherwise, you could accomplish the same using the `reshape` function which will give you what you want. Mark you this is Base R:

```
reshape(data.frame(df1), timevar = 'trip_id', idvar = c('id', 'name'), dir='wide', sep = '_')

  id  name    date_10 cost_10    date_11 cost_11    date_30 cost_30    date_32 cost_32
1  1 james 2021/01/01     100 2021/06/01     150       <NA>      NA       <NA>      NA
3  2 peter 2021/08/01    3000       <NA>      NA       <NA>      NA       <NA>      NA
4  3  anne       <NA>      NA 2021/10/21    1100 2021/10/01    1200 2021/12/01    5000
```